# How does type casting work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, casting

I want to be able to be able to truncate a `float` or `double` in a similar way you would in Java: `(int)5.583`, for example.

I've done some research and, to my knowledge, there's nothing imported in Prelude for this. So I'm wondering how I would construct a function that does it. I thought maybe if I did `show 5.583` and then took a substring up to the decimal point and then converted that to an `Int`, but that seems like it would be terribly inefficient when using only recursion. So is there a more simple way to go about it?

Comment: You may compute a new value from an existing one.  If you wish to compute the floor or ceiling of a float to acquire an integral then call `floor` or `ceiling`.

Comment: There are very different concepts hiding behind the words "type casting" in Java. What you want to do is rather to convert a numeric value.

Comment: You can [search using Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Floating+a%2C+Integral+b%29+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b) which results in [`ceiling`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:ceiling), [`floor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor), [`round`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round) and [`truncate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:truncate)... all part of the Prelude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to be able to be able to truncate `float` or `double`

Delightfully, the function that truncates fractionals to integrals is named "truncate".

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.4/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:truncate

```
λ> truncate 5.583
5
```

Its type is

```
truncate :: (Real a, Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

This is just an ordinary function. Haskell does not have any language feature (or kludge, if you will) akin to type casting in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Converting floating point numbers with ghc is possible with:

```
λ> :m GHC.Float
λ> :t float2Double
float2Double :: Float -> Double
λ> :t double2Float
double2Float :: Double -> Float
λ> :t double2Int
double2Int :: Double -> Int
λ> :t float2Int
float2Int :: Float -> Int
λ> :t int2Double
int2Double :: Int -> Double
λ> :t int2Float
int2Float :: Int -> Float
```

But for floating point numbers to ints I'd recommend using `ceiling`, `round` and `floor`, and `fromIntegral` for backwads conversion.

**Edit**: after reading the question more carefully, @Chris Martin's answer is the correct one:

```
λ> :t truncate
truncate :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

Comment: @chi, `ceiling`, `floor`, `truncate` and `fromIntegral` are mentioned in the answer, so not quite sure why you brought them up. As to `GHC.*` modules, I'd agree with you, those should be used as a last resort. Reason why I mentioned those, because, at first, I mistakenly read that `Float` to `Double` conversion was desired, and the only function that I am aware of which is capable of doing that is `float2Double` from `GHC.Float`.

Comment: Oops. I probably read this too quickly. You are right. The only alternative to `float2Double` I know is `fromRational . toRational`, but it's a bit ugly, and it relies on GHC to optimize this to avoid the intermediate rational representation.